# Should I use a DbContext in my .Net Core Web API or a Service Interface?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I've been given an assessment to complete for a job interview and the assessment is asking me to make a Web API in .Net Core. I've never built a Web API from scratch in .Net Core so I've looked through a lot of tutorials and there is one thing that has been confusing me a lot. In some tutorials the example is using a service interface for handling the business logic between the controller and the model, for example:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-awesome-guide-on-how-to-build-restful-apis-with-asp-net-core-87b818123e28/

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CategoriesController(ICategoryService categoryService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryResource>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var categories = await _categoryService.ListAsync();
        var resources = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<CategoryResource>>(categories);
        
        return resources;
    }
```

And in some tutorials the example is using a DbContext in the controller to implement the CRUD operations for the model, usually automatically generated when adding an Entity Framework scaffolding, for example:

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-build-crud-rest-apis-with-asp-net-core-3-1-and-entity-framework-core-create-jwt-tokens-and-secure-apis.aspx

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly InventoryContext _context;

    public ProductsController(InventoryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Products>>> GetProducts()
    {
        return await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I'm confused as to which way is the right/better way and why? Is it an Entity Framework thing? Does it depend on how complex the models or the relation between the models are?

Documentation and examples of .Net Core are many and doing more research is just sending me in circles. I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me just what I'm dealing with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the database tables represent exactly what users of your service expect. Quite often the database tables have values that you don't want to export to users of the service. In these cases you want to decouple the Database types from the types that you return to the user. If people query data, the database tables are translated into types that you return.

Suppose you have a database with Schools, Teachers and Students. They have the obvious one-to-many relation between Schools and Teachers and between Schools and Students. There is a many-to-many relation between Teachers and Students: every Teacher has zero or more Students, and every Student is taught by zero or more Teachers.

Normally in a relational database, the one-to-many relations are implemented using a foreign key. The many-to-many relation is implemented using a junction table.

### Decoupling returns only data that users expect

Suppose you can query the service for "Schools with their Students". Another query: "Give me Teachers with their Students". Users are not interested in how you get the results. They don't want to know that you use foreign keys and junction tables.

### Decoupling enables you to return data that is not in the database

Decoupling gives you the freedom to give you other data than what is in the database.

"Give me the Schools in city X with their total number of Students". The total number of Students is not anywhere in the Schools table.

### Decoupling enables to leave out sensitive data

This separation between the returned data and the database table gives you the possibility to leave out certain values. If people ask "Give me the Students of Teacher X", they don't expect the foreign key to the School of the Student. You can also leave out behaviour reports of the Students.

### Decoupling allows customizing types for different users

A Teacher who needs to query data for his Students will probably need different data than Students who want to know the addresses of their fellow students. The Teacher might need to know grades. A Student can see his own Grades, but not the Grades of his fellow Students.

### Decoupling enables changing the database

Finally, it gives you the possibility to change the database without having to change the interface of the Service. For example, suppose people complain that if they make a mistake, and accidently delete an item, they can't be undeleted anymore. A popular method is to add a `DateTime?` property `DeletedDate`. The "Delete Student" method will assign a date to `DeletedDate`, it will not delete the Student. If the operator made a mistake, then undelete will be easy: simply assign null to the `DeletedDate` again. A separate process will regularly, let's say once a month, delete the items with a `DeletedDate` older than a year ago, items no one will ever want to undelete again.

### Conclusion

It is a good design to decouple the database tables from the data that you return. It is a design for change, it enable reusability, it is easier for users to understand the data, you can hide your internal structure. The latter also makes unit testing easier.

### Auto mapper or DbContext?

This is not the real difference. The difference is: do you want to use LINQ to translate the data that you fetched into the format that you use, or auto mapper?

IMHO With LINQ it is easier to see what you do when you translate the data. LINQ also does not use reflection, which makes it faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends upon your application architecture and structure. If project contains multiple layers then better to use first approach.

In first approach, Dependency Injection is used which gave the responsibility of creating service class instance to service interface. It is called IoC.

The 2nd approach is simple. If no other layers are used then directly interact with database model through context to get the database data.

Answer (score 0):

In short you want to use a Service layer for your business logic much like your first example. This will give you greater control for many of the reasons other people have already outlined.

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling might seem tedious at first, but when a project grows, it actually simplifies to make changes later on. Regardless if it's a web api, wcf, gRPC or just regular viewmodels for MVC, you will almost always be better off with separate request/response-objects (DTO's if you will).

When it comes to use Automapper or not, I prefer writing extensions or just manually map the data I want to get compile-time errors if I rename anything.